# jcenter fails (504 timeout) when building with piplines

Tags: azure-pipelines

```
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/.... Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
```

These errors seem to be common with Azure Piplines, ubuntu-18.04.  I do not get these errors locally and have no problems connecting to bintray.  Can this be resolved with a build step change?  It looks like it's a network connection or rate limiting issue between bintray and Azure.

Comment: Are you talking about pipelines in Azure DevOps Service? It's using project/project collection build service account to connect bintray. You should also make sure these accounts have access to https://jcenter.bintray.com/. `It looks like it's a network connection or rate limiting issue between bintray and Azure.` Are you using self-host agent or host agent, for self-host agent, please kindly check if you are behind any VPN or firewall blocked the connection.

Comment: Yes, DevOps.  It's a hosted agent, no vpn or firewall.  How do I find out what project/project collection account is being used?  This isn't an 'always fails' situation, it's random.  Some days there are no issues.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Adam, Did you mean you could not find stably reproduce steps of this issue? If it's random, as you have pointed out: one possibility issue may related to network. 504 indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request.  In other words,  azure devops host agent could not connect to `https://jcenter.bintray.com/` succeed.  `Can this be resolved with a build step change? ` Afraid change build step will not work under this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If it's a network issue on azure's side, are there any plans to address it?

Comment: Hi Adam,  It's just a guess at present. Even  though the most likely reason is that there some was glitch in the communication between Azure Pipelines and bintray. But there's no way to tell why it happened; it could have been a fault on either side. Have you tried to use **self-host agent**. Kindly check if it's work in your side.